# Create nodes in a installation profile

Tags: 7

How can I create nodes in a installation profile? Can this be done in the .info file, or does it have to be done in the .install file?

Answer (score 2):

When a profile needs to create something to make it accessible once the profile is installed (e.g. blocks, content types, fields), it does it in its [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x) implementation. For example, the standard profile creates content types, fields, and input formats in its [`standard_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/profiles%21standard%21standard.install/function/standard_install/7.x); it also enables some of the standard blocks, and it set the Seven theme as administrative theme.

Drupal doesn't use any directives in the .info file to automatically create nodes, but a profile could implement code to parse extra directives in a .info file, for example in [`hook_modules_installed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_modules_installed/7.x).

I would rather go with implementing `hook_install()`. I may consider using directives in the .info file if there is a module handling them and I am writing more than three profiles for which being able to change the nodes added from the profile is much important. I understand that avoiding to keep changing the code make less probable to introduce errors; since I know the code to use to create nodes, and the task is relatively simple, using directives in the .info file doesn't simplify much the code I would write for a profile.
I would take more in consideration a module that would back-port to Drupal 7 the code that in Drupal 8 handles the configuration files used to create content types, and fields for those content types, using YAML files. For example, this is the [core/modules/forum/config/optional/node.type.forum.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21config%21optional%21node.type.forum.yml/8.3.x) file that in Drupal 8.3 allows the Forum module to create its content type.

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - forum
name: 'Forum topic'
type: forum
description: 'A <em>forum topic</em> starts a new discussion thread within a forum.'
help: ''
new_revision: false
preview_mode: 1
display_submitted: true
```